# M2MQTT: How to get a subscribe message to persist in .NET for a Web Application (Simple Test)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mqtt

I am currently developing a client subscriber application using the M2MQTT that subscribes to an MQTT broker (mosquitto). I simply want the application to subscribe to the topic, and create a listener that will capture the message sent (sorry I am new to this, and I am a bit rusty on the vernacular).

```
  protected void MqttProcessing()
  {
     // create client instance 
     MqttClient client = new MqttClient(MQTT_BROKER_HOST_NAME);

     // register to message received 
     client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;

     string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     client.Connect(clientId);

     // subscribe to the topic "/home/temperature" with QoS 2 
     client.Subscribe(new string[] { "hello/world" }, new byte  
     {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

  }
```

The above is the recommended set up process to create a client instance, register  to the message received, connect the client, then subscribe to the broker....ok fine I get that. I call this function in:

```
  const string MQTT_BROKER_HOST_NAME = "brokernamehere.com";
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     MqttProcessing();// call to the MQTT client setup steps.
  }
```

Now I believe this is all working as it should,the MQTT connection is able to get a message when I send a message from my mosquitto MQTT client subscriber to the broker, the thing I am having problems wrapping my head around is, how can I grab the message once it gets to the client subscriber and have it persist, so that a user in a web browser can push a button and print the message out and see it in an asp:label tag? Here is what I have in the code behind:

```
  void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
  {
     try
     {
        Session["message"] = "Received = " + 
        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message) + " on topic " + e.Topic;
     }
     catch(HttpException ex)
     {
        Session["message"] = "ERROR:" + ex.Message;
     }
  }
```

If I do the above, the function barfs on the Session["message"] assignment. I debugged this and tried assigning the message to a string variable (tried a local and a global; contained in the partial class) and ***it is able to assign the message to the string variable***...but obviously, it does not persist. The function that handles the button signal is simple:

```
  protected void GetMQTT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {    
        MessContentLabel.Visible = true; 
        MessContentLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["message"]);

  }
```

I was hoping to make use of the Session variable persistence properties, but I think I need something other than a Session variable. There are no simple examples for this on the web I have heard about others doing something similar successfully (see: [MQTT client in MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228445/mqtt-client-in-mvc-application) ), but this gives little clues on my problem.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

So this is testing mosquitto ( https://mosquitto.org/ ) as an mqtt client publisher and broker and the M2MQTT C# .NET mqtt client library for a client subscriber.

I launch the mosquitto application as

```
$>mosquitto
```

Then I launch my web application via Visual Studio. which does the subscription and set up as described above

Next I launch the publisher via mosquitto:

```
$>mosquitto_pub -d -t hello/world -m "HelloWorld"
```

Again, when I debug via Visual Studio 2015 the listener in the web application receives it....  but I am unable to assign it to a variable that persists outside of(what I call) the listener method(?), shown above as  ***MqttMsgPublishReceived***. Again this is a simple test taking place entirely on my laptop.

Hope this additional information provides a clearer picture of what I am attempting.

Comment: Whom is your client receiving messages from ? What are you using on the sending side. Will be able to better assist if you can provide me these details.

Comment: I added a little more to this, describing the publisher, and the broker which are part of mosquitto mqtt.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify QOS 2 and test.

```
mosquitto_pub -d -t hello/world -m "HelloWorld" -q 2
```

Here are the details from online documentation.

> QoS0, At most once: The message is delivered at most once, or it may
>   not be delivered at all. Its delivery across the network is not
>   acknowledged. The message is not stored. The message could be lost if
>   the client is disconnected, or if the server fails. QoS0 is the
>   fastest mode of transfer. It is sometimes called "fire and forget".
>
> The MQTT protocol does not require servers to forward publications at
>   QoS0 to a client. If the client is disconnected at the time the server
>   receives the publication, the publication might be discarded,
>   depending on the server implementation.
>
> QoS1, At least once: The message is always delivered at least once. It
>   might be delivered multiple times if there is a failure before an
>   acknowledgment is received by the sender. The message must be stored
>   locally at the sender, until the sender receives confirmation that the
>   message has been published by the receiver. The message is stored in
>   case the message must be sent again.
>
> QoS2, Exactly once: The message is always delivered exactly once. The
>   message must be stored locally at the sender, until the sender
>   receives confirmation that the message has been published by the
>   receiver. The message is stored in case the message must be sent
>   again. QoS2 is the safest, but slowest mode of transfer. A more
>   sophisticated handshaking and acknowledgement sequence is used than
>   for QoS1 to ensure no duplication of messages occurs.

Cheers !

Comment: Good idea, although I did try to assign the value to a "global" static string (not best practice because of threading issues) and I was able to get the message printed to the asp:label. I will give this a shot. Thanks.